# Are there any callbacks available in the eventbrite api?

Tags: eventbrite

I would like to update a meeting as more people RSVP for the meeting. Currently I do not see any place to enter a callback URL for when attendees RSVP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great suggestion!
Eventbrite does not currently allow a callback url or web hook to be configured, exposing this type of activity.

However, you might be able to build this kind of notification system by placing a tracking pixel (or some similar web asset) on the event's order confirmation page.

If you can detect the HTTP referrer information from the request, it could probably be used to detect the event_id and order_id (which are embedded in the order confirmation page's url path).
Let me know if that works - @RyanJ

Comment: they do have webhooks now https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/reference/webhooks/