# Paypal sandbox integration with eventBrite

Tags: eventbrite

I have integrated EventBirte Ticket widget on my site, when some one buy that ticket and make payment and confirmation URL is there that notify me that payment process done with success or or not, but think is that I need a test run with paypal sandbox, to test all my work process.

One thing more I am using EventBrite PHP API for generating Event and Ticket.

Any one have an idea please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your code [without generating any fees](http://eventbrite.com/fees/) by setting up an event with free tickets.

**Eventbrite is always free to use whenever your tickets are free.**

You should be able to use the Eventbrite API [payment_update](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/payments/payment_update/) method, or the [web-based event administration interface](http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/portal/articles/426298-use-paypal-to-process-orders) to configure your paypal email address (or a paypal sandbox email address).

I would refer to this question for help with post-purchase notification hooks:
[Are there any callbacks available in the eventbrite api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093159/are-there-any-callbacks-available-in-the-eventbrite-api)